# Highcharts Selection Event Disable highlighting Effect

Tags: javascript, highcharts, event-handling, selection

How do I disable the highlighting when I click & drag during selection event on Highcharts? Could I use CSS to mask it? If so what is the class/ID name on this attribute?

[image: Selection Event - Highcharts]

Comment: you want to disable highchart's hover color change event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to set selection color.

From official API:

> **selectionMarkerFill**:
>
> The background color of the marker square when selecting (zooming in on) an area of the chart. Defaults to rgba(51,92,173,0.25).\
>
> *http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.selectionMarkerFill*

If you want to disable selection fill, set `selectionMarkerFill` to `'none'`

```
chart: {
  selectionMarkerFill: 'none',
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/52g0wfqc/

Answer (score 1):

You can disable that `highchart` highlighting event by using this:

```
 plotOptions: {
        series: {
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        }
    }
```